# Particular solution to this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me find the particular solution to this diff equation:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-a\frac{dy}{dx}=C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you differentiate both side, you wind up with $y''' = ay''$, which has $y'' = B_1e^{ax}$ as one solution (where $B_1$ is a constant). (This is totally unnecessary (you could just integrate straight away), but it might help you see what to do.) Integrate, and you have $y' = \frac{B_1}{a}e^{ax} + B_2$ for some other constant $B_2$. Now integrate once more, and you find that $y = \frac{B_1}{a^2}e^{ax} + B_2x + B_3$ for some third constant $B_3$. Now check whether or not the values of the constants $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_3$ have any restrictions imposed on them from the original equation $y''-ay' = C$.

Edit: To determine the $B_i$, note that for $y = \frac{B_1}{a^2}e^{ax} + B_2x + B_3$ the equation $y'' - ay' = C$ says taht

$$
    \left(\frac{B_1}{a^2}e^{ax} + B_2x + B_3\right)'' - a\left(\frac{B_1}{a^2}e^{ax} + B_2x + B_3\right)' = B_1e^{ax} - B_1e^{ax} + B_2 = C,
$$

so $B_2 = C$, and there are no restrictions on $B_1$ and $B_3$.

Comment: How do I find the B constants?

Comment: @Mathguy007 I've updated my answer to explain how.

Answer (score 0):

If the C weren't there, $e^{\lambda t}$ would do it. Do you see the correction needed?

\begin{equation}
y = e^{\lambda t} + At.
\end{equation}

After finding the constants, one particular solution is:

\begin{equation}
y_p = e^{at} - \frac{C}{a} t.
\end{equation}

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If the right side would be 0, an exponential would satisfy the equation. But as a constant is there, you need a constant times t.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-a\frac{dy}{dx}=C$$ or,
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})=C+a\frac{dy}{dx}$$ or,
$$\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})}{C+a\frac{dy}{dx}}=1$$ or,
$$\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(C+a\frac{dy}{dx})}{(C+a\frac{dy}{dx})}=a$$ or, integrating both sides
$$ln(C+a\frac{dy}{dx})=ax+k$$ or,
$$a\frac{dy}{dx}=Ke^{ax}-C$$ or, integrating both sides
$$ay=\frac{1}{a}Ke^{ax}-Cx$$ or,
$$y=\frac{1}{a^2}(Ke^{ax}-aCx)$$
where K is an integration constant = $e^k$

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to sometimes first look at polynomials. Often, the particular solution to an equation is a polynomial. In your case, you can try to find a polynomial such that $y'' = 0$ and $ay' = C$.

Well, since $y'' = 0$, that means the polynomial is linear, $y=kx + n$.

Now, $ay' = C$ gives you that $k=\frac Ca$, so the polynomial $y=\frac Ca + n$ solves your problem for any value $n$.